# Application iptables rule with virtual interfaces

Tags: linux, iptables, interface

If I have two or more network interfaces, ranging from virtual and real, as it could to set iptables rules to affect all of these interfaces?

Example:
I have four interfaces, `eth0`, `eth0:0`, `eth1` and `loopback`, I want to set the following rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

how would this rule to apply it interfaces `eth0`, `eth0:0`, `eth1` and not apply it in `loopback`?

If the rule applies to `eth0` applies in `eth0:0` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the iptables syntax, replace the `-i eth0` with `\! -i loopback` to apply the rule to incoming traffic on all interfaces except loopback.

I'm 99% sure that eth0 and eth0:0 are treated as different interfaces by iptables, so any rule you wish to create needs to be applied separately to each interface.

Comment: But what if I do not specify the interface with the -i? The rule would be applied to all interfaces?

Comment: That is correct.